# How to align button right inside Dialog angular material?

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material2

I want align button right corner of the dialog below is my html

```html
<div mat-dialog-content>
    <p>What's your favorite animal?</p>
    <mat-form-field>
        <input matInput [(ngModel)]="data.animal">
    </mat-form-field>
</div>
<div mat-dialog-actions>

    <button mat-button [mat-dialog-close]="data.animal" cdkFocusInitial>Ok</button>
</div>

<a href="https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ksmixt?file=app/dialog-overview-example-dialog.html">demo</a>
```

Answer (score 76, accepted):

You can use the `align` HTML attribute:

```html
<div mat-dialog-content>
  <p>What's your favorite animal?</p>
  <mat-form-field>
    <input matInput [(ngModel)]="data.animal">
  </mat-form-field>
</div>
<div mat-dialog-actions align="end">
  <button mat-button [mat-dialog-close]="data.animal" cdkFocusInitial>Ok</button>
</div>
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/mat-dialog-aligned-actions)

---

Note: The reason why setting an `align="end"` attribute works on the dialog's actions container is because the `align` attribute is used to add flexbox properties to the dialog actions in the dialog component's theming SCSS file:

*(Extract of `dialog.scss`)*

```scss
.mat-dialog-actions {
  // ...
  &[align='end'] {
    justify-content: flex-end;
  }

  &[align='center'] {
    justify-content: center;
  }
}
```

Here's the [source code](https://github.com/angular/components/blob/07f6a4892cbe44fbb66ff2ded5cdef92087bd5aa/src/material/dialog/dialog.scss#L56-L62).

Comment: Since the align attribute is [not supported in HTML5](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_div_align.asp), look at [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53765847/5208606) to have the CSS equivalent.

Comment: I've updated the answer to note on what the `align` attribute actually does. (EDIT: Didn't see the answer below!)

Comment: Ugh. Why didn't they defined align using `@Input()` instead and add the correct classes to it instead? Then the possible values would be documented and not be marked as an error in my editor.

Answer (score 62):

Since the `align` attribute [is not supported in HTML5](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_div_align.asp), you should use this CSS instead:

```
.mat-dialog-actions {
    justify-content: flex-end;
}
```

*This is what is done internally by Angular Material when you put `align="end"`, you can inspect the element to check that.*

Comment: this should be the correct answer, lints can tell that property "align" is deprecated.

Comment: This is not working with angular material 15

Answer (score 3):

Use the build in toolbar that is part of material.

```
<h4 mat-dialog-title>
        <mat-toolbar role="toolbar" class="task-header">
            <span> Edit Task</span>
            <span class="fx-spacer"></span>
            <button mat-icon-button (click)="close()">
                <mat-icon mat-list-icon>close</mat-icon>
            </button>
        </mat-toolbar>
    </h4>
    <div mat-dialog-content>
    Modal Content here
    </div>
```

Custom CSS for header

```
.task-header {
    background-color: transparent;
    padding: 0 5px;
    height: 20px;
}
.fx-spacer {
    flex: 1 1 auto;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Guess i'm a bit late but anyway.
you can use `float` style attribute:

```html
<button 
    mat-button 
    [mat-dialog-close]="data.animal" 
    cdkFocusInitial style="float: left;">
    Ok
</button>
```

I used inline styling for easier demonstration
but I don't recommend inline styling for your projects.
use seperate style sheets instead

Answer (score 1):

Close functionality and button alignment without TypeScript.

HTML:

```
<button class="button-close" mat-button [mat-dialog-close]="true">X</button>
```

CSS:

```
.button-close {
    justify-self: right;
    font-size: 20px;
    border: none;
    height: 30px;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    outline: none;
    color: #c04747;
    
    &:hover {
        cursor: pointer;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For angular 15 you can set justify-content: flex-end:

```
<div mat-dialog-actions style="justify-content: flex-end">
```

Or in css:

```
.mat-mdc-dialog-actions {
  justify-content: flex-end;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove

```
{display: flex}
```

styling for class mat-dialog-actions

Comment: i have multiple popups if i go and remove  {display: flex} everything will gone right .for this particular popup button need to be right corner