# angular 8 material dialog close button with X top right

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript, angular-material

I am trying to get my material dialog to have an X button at the top right, but I am having problems with the positioning.

component.ts

```
this.d.open(loginComponent, {
  width: '300px',
  height: '',
  panelClass: 'dialogC',
});
```

component.html

```
<mat-dialog-content>
    <button mat-button class="close-icon" [mat-dialog-close]="true">
        <mat-icon>close</mat-icon>
    </button>
    <h2 mat-dialog-title>Login</h2>
```

style.scss

```
.dialogC {
  position: relative !important;
}

.close-icon {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  transform: translate(50%, -50%);
}
```

The X is just aligned to the left instead of top right.  Suggestions?

**Update, this is the problem I get after adding flex:**

[image]

Answer (score 27, accepted):

```
<button class="close" mat-button (click)="onNoClick()">X</button>
<h1 mat-dialog-title>Login</h1>
<div mat-dialog-content>
...
...
</div>
```

**CSS:** (Please give it in global (*styles.css*) or give `ViewEncapsulation.NONE` or else these styles wont affect.)

```
.cdk-overlay-pane.my-dialog {
  position: relative!important;
}
.close.mat-button {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  padding: 5px;
  line-height: 14px;
  min-width: auto;
}
```

Note that in the CSS We now have a new class out of thin air **`.my-dialog`**

So, please mention that as `panelClass` in `dialogRef` like below,

```
this.dialog.open(DialogComponent, {
      width: '250px',
      panelClass: 'my-dialog',
..
..
```

This yields me the following result,

[image]

Comment: Perfect.  I had to modify it with the "close" image and I added "tabindex='-1'" to the button, but perfect!

Comment: @Chris But the question was on placing the "x" button on the top-right corner. Closing the dialog was never an issue!

Comment: How can we add that cancel icon outside the dialog?

Answer (score 34):

The easy way now is:

```
<div mat-dialog-title class="dialog-title">
  <h2>Title</h2>
  <button mat-icon-button aria-label="close dialog" mat-dialog-close>
    <mat-icon>close</mat-icon>
  </button>
</div>
```

And the dialog-title css is

```
.dialog-title {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}
```

That's working on Angular 8.0.0

Answer (score 19):

Using `mat-icon-button` it is necessary to add only the style below to the button.

```
.close-button{
  float: right;
  top:-24px;
  right:-24px;
}
```

Functional example:

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/mat-dialog-close?embed=1&file=src/app/dialog/dialog-component.html)

Comment: How can we add that cancel icon outside the dialog?

Comment: @prasannakumarchebrolu see the `openDialog2` method here
[app-component.ts](https://stackblitz.com/edit/mat-dialog-close?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp-component.ts)

and the css rules for the `.icon-outside` class here
[dialog-component.css](https://stackblitz.com/edit/mat-dialog-close?file=src%2Fapp%2Fdialog%2Fdialog-component.css)

Comment: This answer can be marked as approved as well. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can have the `X` at the title and `display: flex` ? Like this,

```
<div mat-dialog-title class="flex-container">
  <h1>Login</h1>
   <button mat-button class="close-icon" [mat-dialog-close]="true">
        <mat-icon>close</mat-icon>
    </button>
</div>
<div mat-dialog-content>
...
...
</div>
```

FlexBox to the rescue,

```
.flex-container { display: flex;}
```

*SideNote: You can still use `fxLayout` instead of `.flex-container`*

Comment: This will move the button to the right parallel to the title.  The button is still the height of the title and the dialog still has huge padding and margins.  This does not fix the problem.

Comment: I just added an image so you can see what it does with flex.  It will go higher, but just not overlayed on top of dialog.

Answer (score 3):

In your component HTML file add the following markup at the top of all elements.

```
<div mat-dialog-title style="float: right; font-weight: 700; cursor: pointer;" (click)="close()">X</div>
```

In your component TS file add the close function as follows.

```
close(): void {
    this.dialogRef.close();
}
```

Don't forget to include the dialogRef inside the constructor as an argument

```
constructor(public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<YourDialogComponent>) {}
```

Comment: You can use &times; instead of X to get a better view of the close icon.

Answer (score 2):

What I prefer is doing something like this -

.html file

```
<button class="close" mat-button mat-dialog-title (click)="closeDialog()">X</button>
```

By giving mat-dialog-title to the button I make sure it is in the top layer and then I give custom class to it, something like

.css file

```
.close.mat-button {
    position: inherit;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    padding: 2px;
    line-height: 3px;
    min-width: auto;
  }
```

The button discussed above and my modal-content is in a parent div, which I display as flex and use as flex-direction: column

```
.dialog{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
```

.ts file

````
  closeDialog() {
    this.dialogRef.close();
  }```
````

Answer (score 2):

You can acheive this by applying some css styles to mat-icon, you can achieve this.

Mat-dialog looks as below.

```
<button mat-icon-button class="close-button" [mat-dialog-close]="true">
  <mat-icon class="close-icon" color="warn">close</mat-icon>
</button>
<h1 mat-dialog-title>Hi {{data.name}}</h1>
<div mat-dialog-content>
  <p>Hello World!</p>
</div>
```

Add the following css rules

```
// if you want to change the color of the icon
.material-icons.color_white {color: #ffffff;}
.close-button{
  float: right;
  top:-24px;
  right:-24px;
}

//if you want some css animation
.close-icon {
  transition: 1s ease-in-out;
}

.close-icon:hover {
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}

//To place the x mark outside of the container
::ng-deep .icon-outside .close-button{
  float: right;
  top:-52px;
  right:-52px;
}

::ng-deep .icon-outside .mat-dialog-container {
 overflow: unset
}
```

Your mat-dialog consuming componnet should look as below

```
constructor(public dialog: MatDialog) {}

  openDialog(): void {
    const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(DialogComponent, {
      width: '250px',
      panelClass:'icon-outside',
      data: {name: 'your name'}
    });

    dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
      console.log('The dialog was closed');
    });
  }
```

Adding custom class `icon-outside` is important.

This will change your code as expected.
If you are seeking to change the color of the icon, Add these two classes to mat-icon `material-icons` & `color_white`

So your button will look as below:

```
<button mat-icon-button class="close-button icon-outside" [mat-dialog-close]="true">
  <mat-icon class="close-icon material-icons color_white">close</mat-icon>
</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

I just ran into the same problem. I've come up with an easier solution using floats. This also aligns the close X with the title, which I find more visually pleasing.

HTML file:

```
<div>
  <h1 mat-dialog-title style="float: left">Dialog Title</h1>
  <span style="float: right" [mat-dialog-close]>X</span>
</div>

<div mat-dialog-content style="clear: both">
  ...
</div>
```

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

On our project I did an implementation using flex and css.

.html file

```
<div fxLayout="column">
    <div fxLayoutAlign="end">
        <button mat-icon-button color="primary" (click)="close()"><mat-icon>close</mat-icon></button>
    </div>
    <mat-card class="pd-2">
         ...  
    </mat-card>
</div>
```

.ts file

```
    openMinimumsModal( ) {
        const dialogRef = this.matDialog.open(OrderMinimumsComponent, {
            width: 'auto',
            panelClass: 'dialog-no-padding',
           data: { ... },
        });
        dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(() => {});
    }

    close(): void {
        this.dialogRef.close();
    }
```

.css file

```
    .dialog-no-padding .mat-dialog-container {
        padding: 0;
    }

    .pd-2 {
        padding: 0 20px 20px 20px !important;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Possible duplicate: [49420069](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49420069/how-to-align-button-right-inside-dialog-angular-material)

Close functionality and button alignment without TypeScript.

HTML:

```
<button class="button-close" mat-button [mat-dialog-close]="true">X</button>
```

CSS:

```
.button-close {
    justify-self: right;
    font-size: 20px;
    border: none;
    height: 30px;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    outline: none;
    color: #c04747;
    
    &:hover {
        cursor: pointer;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have something like this

**html**:

```
<div class="header-and-close">
  <h1 mat-dialog-title>Header</h1>
  <button type="button" mat-icon-button (click)="closeDialog()" class="close-button">
    <mat-icon aria-hidden="false" aria-label="Close icon">close</mat-icon>
  </button>
</div>
```

**ts component:**

```
  constructor(private dialogRef: MatDialogRef<YourComponent>) {}

  closeDialog() {
    this.dialogRef.close();
  }
```

**css:**

```
.header-and-close {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had to add the close button to many dialogs. I used to implement dialogs using a wrapper component and dynamically instantiated component inside, but I figured it is excessively complex and not flexible. The only thing is that now I have to add the closing button to the dialogs separately. So I made it as a directive. Here's my implementation:

dialog-title.directive.ts

```
import {
    Directive,
    OnInit,
    Renderer2,
    ViewContainerRef,
    ElementRef,
} from '@angular/core';
import { DialogCloseButtonComponent } from './dialog-close-button/dialog-close-button.component';


@Directive({
    selector: `[dialogTitle]`,
    standalone: true,
    host: {
        '[style.display]': '"flex"',
        '[style.justify-content]': '"space-between"',
        '[style.align-items]': '"baseline"',
        '[style.padding]': '"10px 24px"',
    },
})
export class DialogTitleDirective implements OnInit {
    constructor(
        private renderer: Renderer2,
        private viewContainerRef: ViewContainerRef,
        private elementRef: ElementRef,
    ) {}

    ngOnInit() {
        const closeButton = this.viewContainerRef.createComponent(DialogCloseButtonComponent);
        this.renderer.appendChild(this.elementRef.nativeElement, closeButton.location.nativeElement);
    }
}
```

dialog-close-button.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { MatButtonModule } from '@angular/material/button';
import { MatDialogModule } from '@angular/material/dialog';
import { MatIconModule } from '@angular/material/icon';


@Component({
    selector: 'app-dialog-close-button',
    standalone: true,
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
        MatButtonModule,
        MatDialogModule,
        MatIconModule,
    ],
    templateUrl: './dialog-close-button.component.html',
    styleUrl: './dialog-close-button.component.scss'
})
export class DialogCloseButtonComponent {}
```

dialog-close-button.component.html

```
<button mat-dialog-close mat-icon-button aria-label="Close dialog">
    <mat-icon>close</mat-icon>
</button>
```

And finally, you use it in your dialog's template as follows:

```
<h1 dialogTitle>Title of you dialog goes here</h1>
```

Result:

[image: Result: Angular Material dialog with a title and close button using directive]

*Just make sure you have imported DialogTitleDirective in your component / module.