# How to Add Cancel Icon or Button Outside for Mat dialog

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I want to add Cancel Icon Outside for Mat-Dialog when its opened.

For reference:
https://stackblitz.com/angular/dgjvllndexp?file=app%2Fdialog-content-example.html

ThankYou in advance.

Comment: Have u check this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58151512/angular-8-material-dialog-close-button-with-x-top-right

Comment: Yeah, I have Checked. But i want to add cancel icon outside of Mat-dialog.

Comment: what do mean to add cancel icon outside dialog?

Comment: Here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58151512/angular-8-material-dialog-close-button-with-x-top-right
They add cancel icon on Top right inside of Mat-dialog . I want that cancel icon Top right Outside of Mat-dialog.

Comment: you have `const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(DialogContentExampleDialog, {` in your stackblitz. you can do `this.dialogRef.close()` anywhere you need

Comment: Yes, By Clicking cancel icon I want to close the dialog

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First your dialog container should be positioned to relative and x-button to absolution position. Then on x-button, set to top:0;right:0; and translate(100%,-100%).

It should position it as you want. See  my stackblitz
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-e8aunf

Comment: That's what i am looking For.. Thank You